# Julia: confusion with error on datatype / DataFrame

Tags: julia

New to Julia. Following this blog to do Neural Network:

http://blog.yhathq.com/posts/julia-neural-networks.html

I am confused about data types and error messages in Julia. This is my code (again, following the blog post on Neural Network):

```
# read in df to train
train_df = readtable("data/winequality-red.csv", separator=';')
# create train and test data splits
y = train_df[:quality]
x = train_df[:, 1:11] # matrix of all except quality
# vector() and matrix() from blog post

n = length(y)
is_train = shuffle([1:n] .> floor(n * .25))

x_train,x_test = x[is_train,:],x[!is_train,:]
y_train,y_test = y[is_train],y[!is_train]

type StandardScalar
  mean::Vector{Float64}
  std::Vector{Float64}
end

# initialize empty scalar
function StandardScalar()
  StandardScalar(Array(Float64, 0), Array(Float64, 0))
end

# compute mean and std of each col
function fit_std_scalar!(std_scalar::StandardScalar, x::Matrix{Float64})
  n_rows, n_cols = size(x_test)
  std_scalar.std = zeros(n_cols)
  std_scalar.mean = zeros(n_cols)

  for i = 1:n_cols
    std_scalar.mean[i] = mean(x[:,i])
    std_scalar.std[i] = std(x[:,i])
  end
end

# further vectorize the transformation
function transform(std_scalar::StandardScalar, x::Matrix{Float64})
  # element wise subtraction of mean and division of std
  (x .- std_scalar.mean') ./ std_scalar.std'
end

# fit and transform
function fit_transform!(std_scalar::StandardScalar, x::Matrix{Float64})
  fit_std_scalar!(std_scalar, x)
  transform(std_scalar, x)
end

# fit scalar on training data and then transform the test
std_scalar = StandardScalar()

n_rows, n_cols = size(x_test)

# cols before scaling
println("Col means before scaling: ")
for i = 1:n_cols
  # C printf function
  @printf("%0.3f ", (mean(x_test[:, i])))
end
```

I am getting the error:

```
'.-' has no method matching .-(::DataFrame, ::Array{Float64,2}) in fit_transform! ...
```

For this code:

```
x_train = fit_transform!(std_scalar, x_train)
x_test = transform(std_scalar, x_test)

# after transforming
println("\n Col means after scaling:")
for i = 1:n_cols
  @printf("%0.3f ", (mean(x_test[:,i])))
end
```

I am new to Julia and am just not understanding what the issue is. Vector() and Matrix() do not work from the blog post. I assume that was from an older version of DataFrame.

What I think my issue is: these functions are taking in ::Matrix{Float64} and I am passing in the DataFrame. I assume that deprecated (?) Matrix() would have fixed this? Not sure. How do I analyze this error and pass these functions the correct types (if that is the problem here)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message says that you're attempting an element-wise subtraction, `.-`, between a `DataFrame` and an `Array` but that operation has no definition for those types.  A silly example of this sort of situation:

```
julia> "a" .- [1, 2, 3]
ERROR: `.-` has no method matching .-(::ASCIIString, ::Array{Int64,1})
```

My guess is that if you add

```
println(typeof(x_train))
```

in front of

```
x_train = fit_transform!(std_scalar, x_train)
```

that you'll be told that it's a `DataFrame` rather than an array that you're trying to work with.  I'm not experienced with the DataFrame library but may be able to dig up the conversion tomorrow sometime.  This is all I have time for just now.

*Added comments after obtaining data file*

I retrieved *winequality-red.csv* and worked with its `DataFrame`

```
julia> VERSION
v"0.3.5"

julia> using DataFrames

julia> train_df = readtable("data/winequality-red.csv", separator=';')

julia> y = train_df[:quality]
1599-element DataArray{Int64,1}:

julia> x = train_df[:, 1:11]
1599x11 DataFrame

julia> typeof(x)
DataFrame (constructor with 22 methods)
```

`x` and `y` are at this point *array-like* objects.  The blog post apparently uses `vector` and `matrix` to convert these to true arrays, but these functions are unfamiliar to me.  As IainDunning points out in his answer (*I'd like to cite this properly but haven't puzzled that out yet*), this conversion is now done via `array`.  Perhaps this is what you need to do:

```
julia> y = array(train_df[:quality])
1599-element Array{Int64,1}:

julia> x = array(train_df[:, 1:11])
1599x11 Array{Float64,2}:
```

I've not followed through with an analysis of all of the other code, so this is a hint at the answer rather than a fully fleshed out and tested solution to your problem.  Please let me know how this it works out if you give it a try.

I'm accustomed to seeing and using `Array{Float64,1}` and `Array{Float64,2}` rather than `Vector{Float64}` and `Matrix{Float64}`.  Possibly the vector and matrix synonyms for specific types of arrays is deprecated.

Comment: Yes, that is what I figured was happening. I should have explicitly said that I understand the error is from ".-" (the element wise subtraction). Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for that clarification.  I just wanted to make that detail explicit, particularly since you said that you're new to Julia (as am I).  I've since grabbed the data file and played with it.  I believe that I see the solution, which is pretty much what @IainDunning suggested.  I'll supplement my answer with this information.

Comment: Exactly! I figured it out a bit before you edited with the solution. No more vector(...) nor matrix(...), instead simply array(...) for both. Also, I have seen a lot of 'old' syntax for train_df["quality"] which does NOT work. It should be train_df[:quality] - just for anyone else. Thank you Iain and Mike! I successfully created an artificial neural network prediction model :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe `vector(...)` and `matrix(...)` were both replaced with just `array(...)`, but I can't find an issue number to correspond with that change.